# Correction in regular expression please

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading the serial port using port.ReadExisting() to read incoming calls from a GSM modem in c#. I stored the read data in a string variable s. Now i want to compare the incoming data with a regular expression. But the while condition is never executed. Please provide correction.

The incoming data on port is

```
RING

+CLIP: "+919030665834",145,"",,"",0
```

I have written the following code:

```
                string s = port.ReadExisting();  
                Regex r = new Regex(@"\r\n(.+)\r\n\+CLIP: ""\+(\d+)"",(.+),""(.*)"",(.*),""(.*)"",(\d+)\r\n");  
                Match m = r.Match(s);  
                while (m.Success)  
                {  
                    if (s.Contains("\r\nRING\r\n"))  
                    {  
                        call_status.Text = "Incoming Call";  
                        call_status.Visible = true;  
                        status_phno.Text = m.Groups[1].Value;  
                    }  
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, "RING[^\\+]*\\+CLIP:\\s*\"(?<phone>[^\"]*)\",(\\d+),\"([^\"]*)\",(\\w*),\"(\\w*)\",(\\w*)");

if(match.Success && inputString.Contains("RING"))
{
    var phoneNumber = match.Groups["phone"].Value;
}
```

I skipped any character except '+' first : `[^\+]*`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there should be two newlines between the .+ matching "RING" and +CLIP. So the regex would read \r\n(.+)\r\n\r\n+CLIP: ...

Otherwise, this should be an easy problem to debug--just start replacing bigger and bigger sections, starting from the front or the back, with ".*". Once it starts matching, you know that the part that you just fed into the .* was the section causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regular expression:

"RING[^\+]*\+CLIP:\s*\"(?[^\"]*)\",(\d+),\"([^\"]*)\",(\w*),\"(\w*)\",(\w*)"